# Remove http from variable

Tags: php

I have a variable, such as this:

```
$domain = "http://test.com"
```

I need to use preg_replace or str_place to get the variable like this:

```
$domain = "test.com"
```

I have tried using the following, but they do not work.

```
1) $domain = preg_replace('; ((ftp|https?)://|www3?\.).+? ;', ' ', $domain);
2) $domain = preg_replace(';\b((ftp|https?)://|www3?\.).+?\b;', ' ', $domain);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Or you can use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$domain = ltrim($domain, "http://");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. That worked. :) Is there anyway to also remove anything after .com ?

Comment: If you want to extract just the domain, then, the best thing is to use parse_url(), as suggested by Mickael.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the str_replace?

```
$domain = "http://test.com"
$domain = str_replace('http://','',$domain);
```

You regular expressions probably don't find a match for the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('~(https://|http://|ftp://)~',, '', $domain);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[a-z]+:[/][/](.+)$/', $domain, $matches);
echo($matches[1]);
```

Should be what you are looking for, should give you everything after the protocol... http://domain.com/test becomes "domain.com/test". However, it doesn't care about the protocol, if you only want to support specific protocols such as HTTP and FTP, then use this instead:

```
preg_match('/^(http|ftp):[/][/](.+)$/', $domain, $matches);
```

If you only want the domain though, or similar parts of the URI, I'd recommend PHP's parse_url() instead. It does all the hard work for you and does it the proper way. Depending on your needs, I would probably recommend you use it anyway and just put it all back together instead.

Answer (score 0):

simple regex:

```
preg_replace('~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i','', 'https://www.site.com.br');
```